# How do I report a problem in civicrm_api3 class?

Tags: api

I am using civicrm_api3 class with the REST api, and Options do not get handled correctly because the code does not allow for an array within the overall parameters array.

I have it fixed  (it is a very simple fix), but I don't know who I should let know.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure for reporting bugs is detailed at https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting . This goes through verifying and reproducing the bug, and then it can be added on the issue tracker.

If you have a patch, you can submit a pull request on GitHub (often against https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core) with a reference to the bug report.